# jTextfield display problem in java

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have made a frame in which i have put two jTextfield boxes where the user can see the path of the loaded file.  Problem is that if the path is too long , the textfield expands to accomodate the full path which again leads to display problems. I would like to keep the textfield's length constant and instead , display the full path of file as a tooltip instead.

How can this be done?

Code for layout manager of jinternal Frame:

```
   javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
```

Comment: Which `LayoutManager` do you use?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 6.8. So the code is auto generated. i hope this helps. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: 
Anybody having the same problem can set the Property Columns using Netbeans. The default is 0, so the textfield cannot accomodate the full text. Use some value like 3 to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I never use an IDE so I don't know how the GroupLayout works.

But when using the other layout managers I always use:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10); // or whatever size your want
```

This will give the text field a preferred size and the layout manager can use that information when laying out the component.

Answer (score 1):

Code the GUI by hand instead.  You will avoid problems like this and it will be much easier to make changes to your code.

Comment: +1, it is also better to spend time learning Java, rather than learning an IDE. Since the OP doesn't understand the code generated by the IDE he has no idea how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to choose a layout manager to manage the proportions of your JComponents.
Try to put your textfiels on a JPanel so you can select a layout useful for you

Later you can use JTextField. setToolTip("full path") to set a tool tip

Comment: I will have to change too much if i do that. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you are using Netbeans, then you could attach your components to theirs surroundings very easy. Look on this tutorial maybe it could help http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html

Comment: can i replace my internal frames with jpanel without affecting the textfields on top of it?

Comment: each frame has a internal panel, inside this panel you can put any other JComponent (JPanel, JTextField, etc). Look for the docs for each class and you will find the specific methods and the hierarchy of each object